# Xamarin.Forms for WPF TapGestureRecognizer double-click not firing for a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a simple app that I want to do in Xamarin, and I have two pages with ListViews with a simple label for each cell.

I want to be able to both SELECT a line (click), and initiate an EDIT of the line by double-clicking.  I was able to do this in UWP with TapGestureRecognizer with NumberOfTapsRequired="2".

But, this doesn't seem to work with UWP.  I thought maybe I had to switch to ClickGestureRecognizer, but I could not get that to work at ALL in WPF. In desperation, I'm provide the user a "context action" for edit, which (gladly), does work, but is not preferred.

```
<ListView x:Name="itemList" >
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ViewCell>
       <ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <MenuItem
           Clicked="MenuItemEdit_Clicked"
           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
           Text="Edit" />
         </ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding}" >
           <Label.GestureRecognizers>
             <TapGestureRecognizer 
               NumberOfTapsRequired="2" 
               Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_2Tapped" />
           </Label.GestureRecognizers>
         </Label>
       </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Xamarin.Forms/
Has anyone else tried/seen this?  Any other suggestions?  And, any thoughts on how much WPF will be supported going forward?

Comment: Hi , I have checked in local site , the same problem with you . It seems  `GestureRecognizers` not works in WPF. Because WPF is a preview support in Xamarin from 4.7, maybe this is a conflict. I will continue to check the solution , if good news will update here .

Comment: I have found "tap" is recognized, but not "click" or "swipe".  IMHO it's time for WPF to become a "first class" Xamarin Citizen.

Comment: Okey , glad it works as "tap" .  Yeah , also think that WPF will be in the near future .

Comment: Update: I "faked it", by capturing time between taps -- less than 300 msec => double tap.  Then, I decided that the quirks I was facing with WPF and Xamarin were a bit too much.

Comment: Oh, that should be a good workaround! Later if Xamarin solves this , we can use `TapGestureRecognizer` to achieve that more simpler. You can update this workadround in answer , then other people will know how to solve the same issue when they have. :-)